# App preventing Windows 11 from shutdown

Tags: windows-11, shutdown, reboot

A process with the following icon is preventing Windows 11 Pro for Workstations, 22H2, OS build 22621.2361 from shutdown and/or restart:

[image]

I've tried to identify it, but failed - there is nothing in the logs, no path to software, no name of the process. MS Process Explorer do not show any process with this icon.

Anyone would know what it is and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Try SysInternals Process Monitor and also see if it is starting up using SysInternals Autoruns

Comment: The shutdown message contains the name of the process. What does it say?

Comment: @John thanks, tried both, but this icon is nowhere. In meantime I found this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/does-anyone-know-what-this-red-yellow-blue-icon-is/92a7e2f3-8c3f-4651-a62d-59252d0d8308 which probably means I can be in deep troubles :(

Comment: @harrymc That icon above with text: This app is preventing shutdown.

Comment: Btw. followed suggestions there: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/does-anyone-know-what-this-red-yellow-blue-icon-is/92a7e2f3-8c3f-4651-a62d-59252d0d8308

It is not graphic or scanner drivers.

Comment: See if you can see this icon in Task Manager, Startup tab.

Comment: @harrymc - it is nowhere, the reason being "That icon is the default icon for an Application programmed in C# with SharpDevelop for Windows, so it will be hard to narrow this down".

Microsoft mess.

Comment: Suggestion: Shutdown Windows, wait for it to stop everything that it can, then cancel the shutdown and use Task Manager to look for such a running process.

Comment: @harrymc There is quite a few processes running. But without icon matching is hard to tell which doesn't close on shutdown.

Comment: Task Manager, Processes tab, also shows the icon.

Comment: @harrymc They indeed do - just not the one above.

Comment: Just for a good measure I've uninstalled recent updates: KB5030651, KB5029921 and KB5030310. It is not that either. It seems that @John is right - Windows is a living organism and it simply dies at some point.

Comment: Autoruns can help you identify software automatically starting

Comment: @Ramhound John suggested SysInternals Process Monitor and SysInternals Autoruns as the first option. Nothing is there. As the last resort I am trying Windows Performance Recorder.

Comment: Also, the icon is the default icon for a program created with Visual Studio .Net

Comment: Windows degrading is an absolute old wife’s tale, I have had the same exact installation that I have ported to multiple machines over a decade. What fails is the storage device.

Comment: @Ramhound I thought the same before this. But being literally unable identify process which prevents system from shutdown is bad.

I've tried all the tools suggested by MS certified professionals (Process Explorer, Process monitor, Autoruns, Windows Performance Analyzer), but as far as I get is "Unknown". No path, no name, no PID.

It can be anything. System without functional debugging tools is extremely dangerous and costly thing.

Comment: I am going to give up. Now, after some uninstalls, I am getting at the shutdown an additonal: reg exe this application was unable to start correctly 0xc0000142...

Answer (score 3):

I've upvoted LPChip's answer, because it have sent me the right direction even if his suggestion wasn't the source of the problem.

The issue was indeed connected with development - it was/still is an issue in Docker Desktop for Windows. Its update 4.23 (and all the following versions) breaks the shutdown: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13697. (Notice the icon.)

It wasn't installed recently, hence I didn't suspect it, but after disabling background development tools the system started working again.

For all of you having the same issue, you need to close background Docker manually before shutting down.

Comment: So it's at least good news that it's nothing "nefarious"?

Comment: Well, there always could be hackers using MS Visual Studio, but most likely when you see this icon it is Windows showing you where the the process source could be edited.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you say it is a development machine, and the icon is the default icon for Microsoft Visual Studio, you are likely facing one of the things I had happen.

During development, your executable does not properly exit and remains in memory, as it is in a crashing/exiting stage during windows shutdown.

See if you can find your own application in memory, and if so, kill it, and see if that makes the problem go away. Another test you can do, restart your computer, don't open your development software and restart again, see if it happens, if not, open your development software, build and run it, and restart afterwards, should now happen again.

Do note, the icon in task manager will NOT be the one you see here. I don't know why that icon only appears in some places and not others if you don't set a specific icon in your program.

Comment: The icon has to be programmed. If this is a new project that code wouldn’t have been added yet. I agree it’s the authors own application that’s causing their problem. Since it’s not an executable being automatically ran.  Furthermore, malware, is NOT coded in c# since it can be easily decompiled

Comment: If only I'd do C# development. I do Python, PHP and JS. This seems to be indeed connected with .NET, but not my code. It must be connected with some software which requires .NET library, which became incompatible in time.

But unfortunately none of Process Explorer, Process monitor, Autoruns or Windows Performance Analyzer gave me anything.

Comment: Do you convert your python scripts to an executable?